# Rename index across multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, rename

I have a function:

```
def func(df):
    #does stuff
     return df
```

The returned DataFrame looks like the following when I input a dataframe:

```
     x1   x2   x3 
ret 
vol
```

I wish to change the name of the index, which in this case is `ret` and `vol`.

As I have multiple dataframes (`a`, `b`,`c` etc..) which I want to run this function over, I have manually done the following:

```
performance_a = (func(a)).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_a','vol':'vol_a'})
performance_b = (func(b)).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_b','vol':'vol_c'})
performance_c = (func(c)).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_b','vol':'vol_c'})
etc...
```

The end output is this:

```
     x1   x2   x3 
ret_a 
vol_a

     x1   x2   x3 
ret_b 
vol_b

etc...
```

Is there an easier way to loop through this ?

Cheers :)

Comment: Not sure what you need here

Comment: Instead of having to do this multiple times -

`performance_a = (func(a)).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_a','vol':'vol_a'})`
`performance_b = (func(b)).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_b','vol':'vol_c'})`
`performance_c = (func(c)).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_b','vol':'vol_c'})`


Is it possible to loop through so the dataframe variable goes where [df] (which would be `a`, `b`, and `c`) is in the example below

`performance_[df] = (func([df])).rename(index = {'ret':'ret_[df]','vol':'vol_[df]'})`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the changing index logic to func()?
Or add a wrapper func_b() that calls func() and apply index rename?